# how to run the asp.net applications in windows 7?

Tags: iis-6, windows-7

I just install windows 7 and visual studio 2008.and turn on the iis in Turn Windows Features On or Off .But my asp.net applications are not saved in iis.It says run the application as administrator.please tell me how to run the asp.net application in iis

Answer (score 1):

By defauld IIS needs admin permission. You can add your user account under Administrator group and you will get admin rights in order to run the application as administrator. Also refer to following URL for more details regarding Building and Running ASP.NET Applications.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/23/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/

Answer (score 0):

First, check you have the required permission to run the application. To know about how to get .NET work with IIS 7, check the below URL

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis-7/

If you can give a clear scenario on your issue, I can have a better try on this.